# Server side scripting issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I have written the server-side scripting to show a large amount of data and it's working fine, but I want to show the sum in the footer of the points column.
The code is written in a laravel blade file.

The footer calls back function, not working it is showing me an error ie an undefined length object, please let me know where I am making the mistake.

```
<table class="table table-bordered yajra-datatable" width="100%" style="color:#8D1B6B;margin-top:20px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Sr No</b></td>
            <td><b>Date</b></td>
            <td><b>Activity Name</b></td>
            <td><b>Activity Marks</b></td>
            <td><b>My Rewards</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
<tfoot>

</tfoot>
</table>
```

The script written for the above code is

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var table = $('.yajra-datatable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: "{{ route('abc') }}",
                columns: [
                    {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
                    {data: 'activityDate', name: 'activityDate'},
                    {data: 'activity', name: 'activity'},
                    {data: 'point', name: 'point'},
                    {
                        data: 'action',
                        name: 'action',
                        orderable: true,
                        searchable: true
                    },
                ],
                "footerCallback": function (row, data, start, end, display) {
                    var api = this.api(), data;
                    // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                    var intVal = function ( i ) {
                        return typeof i === 'string' ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 : typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
                    };
                    // Total over all pages
                    data = api.column( 3 ).data();

                    total = data.length ? data.reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    }) : 0;

                    // Total over this page
                    data = api.column( 3, { page: 'current'} ).data(); pageTotal = data.length ? data.reduce( function (a, b) { return intVal(a) + intVal(b); } ) : 0;

                    // Update footer
                    $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html( '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)' );
                }
            });

           
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: "But for the footer it is not working"  - what does that mean? Are you facing any error message? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why is this tagged with Laravel, but you haven't shared any PHP code?

Comment: The whole point of server-side processing is so that DT doesn't have to load all the data at one time. When you use server side processing, the table will never have all the data, so your counts will never be accurate. You'll need to make a separate API request to the server to get the total count instead of trying to get that data from DT.

Comment: I mean to say that, not getting sum in the footer rest of the body part is working fine

Comment: @WebDeveloper - Yes, but you are using the DT API to get the data. You are making the assumption that you can get the "total over all pages" from DataTables, which you cannot, not when you're using serverside processing.

Comment: Also, you need to be more specific than just saying "it's not working." You need to tell us what is not working exactly. What behavior did you expect, and what behavior happened instead. I'm assuming the counts are just wrong, which would make sense.

Comment: Okay. I know that I will not get all total at a time, because I am using server-side scripting.

The output In output I am getting tbody values but in tfoot not getting anything I want the sum of points in the footer